# How to clear database after each integration test in NestJS and TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I used TypeORMModule to provide config for the DataSource:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          type: 'postgres',
          // host has to be the container name of the database
          host: config.get<string>('POSTGRES_HOST'),
          port: parseInt(config.get('POSTGRES_PORT')),
          username: config.get<string>('POSTGRES_USER'),
          password: config.get<string>('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
          database: config.get<string>('POSTGRES_DB'),
          synchronize: true,
          entities: [User],
        };
      },
    }),
    UsersModule,
  ],
})
```

How do I go about clearing the database for each test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got `dataSource` from `app.get(DataSource)` and applied delete:

```js
afterEach(async () => {
    const dataSource = app.get(DataSource);
    await dataSource.createQueryBuilder().delete().from(User).execute();
  });
```

Comment: I tried running query to truncate as [@reginald](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76347038/13962029) recommended, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an utility function that [truncates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html) all your database tables :

```js
async function clearDatabase(app: INestApplication): Promise<void> {
    const entityManager = app.get<EntityManager>(EntityManager);
    const tableNames = entityManager.connection.entityMetadatas
        .map((entity) => entity.tableName)
        .join(', ');

    await entityManager.query(
        `truncate ${tableNames} restart identity cascade;`,
    );
}
```

Then in your test files you'll just have to call this function using `afterEach` :

```js
describe('Context', () => {
    let app: INestApplication;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const appModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [DatabaseModule],
        }).compile();

        app = appModule.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();
    });

    afterEach(async () => {
        await clearDatabase(app);
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await app.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't truncate: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" at character 10`

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
dropSchema: true
```

to the Typeorm config for the test.

Comment: I'm using same config for both test and dev

Comment: dropSchema: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"

Comment: `synchronize: true` only resets the table schemas without dropping tables, it's much more appropriate for testing and development, definitely dangerous in production/staging environments though.